# How to initialize a set with specific number of elements?

Tags: c++, initialization, set

How can I initialize a `std::set<int>` with five elements ?? like arrays I can say `int x[5];`
or vectors I also can use `vector<int> v(5);` how am I supposed to do the same in `std::set<int>` ?

Answer (score 3):

A [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) is supposed to contain unique values, so for initialisation you have to specify these.

You can use the constructor, that takes an `initializer_list`, but you have to specify a set of unique numbers:

```
std::set<int> S { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```